# Как сделать запрос к трем таблицам, с отдельным JOIN по каждой и применить функцию агрегации к результату?

Tags: sql, bigquery

Привет всем знатокам SQL. 
Я новый в этом вопросе достаточно, по этому, прошу помощи.

У меня есть 3 инстансы: 
`instance_1`,`instance_2`, `instance_3`
В каждом из них есть 2 таблицы: 
`crm`, `email`

Т. е. в общей сложности, у меня есть 6 разных таблиц.

В таблице `crm`, есть поля `device_id`, `carrier`
В таблице email - поля `device_id` и `md_5`

Структура таблиц от инстанса к инстансу не меняется. 
Задача: Мне надо вывести все `md_5` из трех инстансов, где одному `md_5` соответстует 2 и больше `carrier` (но не больше, чем 6). Объеденяю таюлицы по полю `device_id`.

Делаю вот как (с помощью bigQuery):

```
SELECT 
crm.device_id,
crm.carrier,
email.md_5,
FROM `instance_1.crm` crm
FULL OUTER JOIN 
`instance_1.email` email 
ON crm.device_id = email.device_id
GROUP BY email.md_5
HAVING COUNT(crm.carrier)>=2
```

При выполениии кода, возникает ошибка

```
SELECT list expression references crm.device_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:1]
```

Почему возникает ошибка, как ее избежать и как объеденить в одну таблицу, результаты с 3-х инстансов?
В моем примере есть данные только с одного инстанса.

Спасибо)

Comment: *Почему возникает ошибка* переведите сообщение об ошибке - там написано. *как ее избежать* Обернуть проблемное поле в групповую функцию (например, MAX()). *как объеденить в одну таблицу, результаты с 3-х инстансов?* UNION ALL либо UNION DISTINCT - в зависимости от задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(crm.device_id),
  COUNT(crm.carrier),
  email.md_5,
FROM `instance_1.crm` crm
FULL OUTER JOIN `instance_1.email` email ON crm.device_id = email.device_id
GROUP BY email.md_5
HAVING COUNT(crm.carrier)>=2
```